# Saving a DF to azure blob

Tags: python, dataframe, azure-blob-storage, etl, data-transfer

I am trying to save a df which is returned from a function (return df). I am trying to push this to my azure blob storage account.

I am having some troubles as all the solutions I have found required a file path, however I just want to run some code on a dataframe and save it automatically to azure blob.

As per requests, a snippet of my code :)

As stated above, I am looking to save the df (a pandas dataframe) as a .csv into the blob, I am not looking for other information.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import os, uuid
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__
```

```
def function (df):
    df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[1]).drop(df.index[0])
    df = df.iloc[1:]
    indexNames = df[df['Customer'].isin(['Stock', 'Sales', 'Over', '2021 Under'])].index
    df = df.drop(indexNames)
    df.columns = df.columns.fillna('ItemNo')
    for col in df:
        df['ItemNo'] = df['ItemNo'].ffill()
        
    
    return df
```

```
CONNECTION_STRING = ""
CONTAINERNAME = ""
BLOBNAME = ""
LOCALFILENAME = "" 

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING) #instantiate new blobservice with connection string
#container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(CONTAINERNAME) #instantiate new containerclient
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container = CONTAINERNAME, blob=BLOBNAME)

#READ PRODUCTS FILE
f = open(LOCALFILENAME, "wb")
f.write(blob_client.download_blob().content_as_bytes())
f.close()
df = pd.read_excel(r''+LOCALFILENAME)
```

Comment: Can you share the code for uploading? Basically if you're able to get a buffer using `DataFrame.to_csv`, you should be able to call [`blob_client.upload_blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#upload-blob-data--blob-type--blobtype-blockblob---blockblob----length-none--metadata-none----kwargs-) method.

Comment: that is the part which I have no idea how to do, and cannot find a resource that helped me enough to write code to go from having a:  df.to_csv -> saved to azure blob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try the following code:

```
    temp_path = tempfile.gettempdir()
    file_path = os.path.join(temp_path, 'dataframe.csv')
    df.to_csv (file_path)
    with open(file_path, "rb") as data:
        blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```